# Protect existing entries in an Access database

Tags: ms-access

I am completely new to Access and have only limited database knowledge. Is it possible to lock/protect an entry made by a specific user so that other users cannot change that field/entry again? Is there also a way to see which user entered the data in that particular field?

Comment: Which Access version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Access does not have the security mechanisms to do what you describe. Even the older - and now deprecated - "User-Level Security" mechanism for Access .mdb files (mentioned in another answer) does not allow you to fully protect entries at the row level.

An earlier question here

[How can I get my Access form to prevent editing of a field once saved?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11870945/2144390)

talks about how to offer such protection from within an Access form, but it does not address the possibility of a user directly opening the table and editing it that way. As such, that question is merely asking for a "convenience" feature to help prevent users from inadvertently changing something. A forms-based control mechanism does *not* offer complete security.

If you need more robust security (e.g. for audit purposes) then you will need to use a different database back-end. You could still use Access to build your forms and reports, but they would operate on ODBC linked tables to a more sophisticated database engine like SQL Server (or similar).

Comment: Post #8 details how to deny user-access to the db window:
http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=176038

Once you have that under control, then all you need to do is manage the user's interaction with data by designing a functional distinction between INSERT & UPDATE.

SQL Server is the daddy for all this stuff clearly, but my feeling is that someone new to Access might struggle to make the most of it without getting bogged down.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but I suspect you have a steep learning curve ahead - here's your jumping-off point :)

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/about-user-level-security-mdb-HP003070410.aspx

Comment: I don't think that User-Level Security (ULS) would offer the kind of protection that the OP is looking for. ULS is also deprecated and has been removed from the newer .accdb file format.

Comment: ULS would definitely answer this issue by managing the use of  queries/tables, but as you suggest we don't know which version of Access they are using